# Create exactly 5 process with fork()

Tags: c, fork

```
For(i=0, i<3, i++){
    Fork()
}
```

Hello, this Code creates 5 process.
How can i create only 3 processes ?
Or how do i create only Child processes ?

Thank you

Comment: This can't be your actual code; C is case-sensitive.  I can answer this question anyway, but for future reference, we always want to see exactly the same code you are trying to use yourself.

Comment: Do you understand how `fork` works? Start from trying to understand it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. [Don't bite the newcomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Please_do_not_bite_the_newcomers).

Comment: @zwol It was not intended to be a bite but a genuine suggestion. This question clearly lacks a basic research on the subject.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You may have intended it as a genuine suggestion, but it's likely to have been understood as a bite. You don't know how much research OP already tried to do before they posted the question. It's quite plausible to me that they _did_ already try to figure it out on their own and got nowhere (e.g. because the `fork` manpage is written for someone who already understands it and just needs a reminder). For someone in that position, "start from trying to understand it" reads as "go away and don't bother us ever again".

Answer (score 2):

When you create a fork, both the parent and the newly created child process continue from the point of forking. So, if you have a loop running three times with fork, the parent creates three children, the first child creates two children, and so on. So, your example will result in more than five processes.

When a fork is created, you can record the pid (process ID). In the child process, the pid value of itself will be 0, while the parent process will have the child's pid stored. You can use this to control subsequent forks.

To create three processes, you can use:

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

// this will be true only in the child process
// so, only the child creates another process, resulting in a total of
// three processes
if (pid == 0) {
    fork();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first call to `fork()`, both the parent and the child process are executing the for-loop, so *both* of them execute the second call to `fork`, and now you have more processes than you wanted.  To fix this you need to make the child do something different than the parent.  You can tell which process is which by looking at the return value of `fork`; it returns 0 in the child and a nonzero value in the parent.  So, something like this:

```
fflush(0); // not directly relevant but always a good idea before forking
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
       _exit(main_for_child(i)); // very important to use _exit, not exit
    }
    // control reaches this point only in the parent
}
```